# Custom shortcode to display in hover

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, divi

I want to display a custom attribute on my products (in category pages) as a hover, but I am having difficulties. In my opinion, the easiest way is to create a shortcode but I can't get over it ...
This is where I am.
This one, to use [product_description id = ’22’] works fine but I need the id to be retrieved automatically.

```
function display_product_description( $atts ){
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' =>  get_the_id(),
    ), $atts, 'product_description' );

    global $product;

    if ( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product') )
        $product = wc_get_product($atts['id']);
    
    return $product->get_attribute( 'Profil aromatique' );
}
add_shortcode( 'product_description', 'display_product_description' );
```

This code also works great but it shows up below my product and I can't get it to hover.

```
function woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title_short_description2() {
    global $product;

    if ( ! $product->get_attribute( 'Profil aromatique' ) ) return;
    ?>
    <div itemprop="description" id="hovertest" class="test" >
        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->get_attribute( 'Profil aromatique' ) ) ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title_short_description2', 5);
```

So, I wanted to make a mix ...

```
function display_profil_description(){
global $product;
    if ( ! $product->get_attribute( 'Profil aromatique' ) ){ return '';}
    else{
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $product->get_attribute( 'Profil aromatique' ) );
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'display_profil_description', 'display_profil_description' );
```

I would like to use it [display_profil_description] and have the ID found on the fly, depending on the product I'm displaying it on. I make the display like this:

```
.woocommerce .et_overlay:before {
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
  margin-top:-50px !important;
    content: '[display_profil_description]';
    /*** YOUR TEXT ***/
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial !important;
    /*** YOUR CHOSEN FONT FAMILY ***/
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    /*** COLOR OF YOUR TEXT ***/
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
```

But it does not work with this shortcode (it works with that of the id) ... My page is displayed super bad (only the menu! Not the content, as if it crashed before everything loads), no error message in console and response 200, no error ...

Could you help me?
After 7 hours of searching, I dry ...

thank you so much

Eva

PS : I use Divi

Answer (score 0):

WordPress/Woocommerce have global variables for current post/product.

Below are two suggestion, try in your shortcode and check which works for you:

1. Using global post variable:
   global $post;
   $id = $post->ID;
2. Using global product variable:
   global $product;
   $id = $product->get_id();

Hope it works! Good Luck.

Comment: Hello ! Thank you very much for your answer.
I try the two but I don't have the production information with the first (only the information of the actual page) and the second is "false" so I don't know have to have the information...
I think the second doesn't work because it is call in CSS ?
Thanks!!